# Wordpress - frequent 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using a wordpress site hosted on a linux shared hosting server, I have a custom developed woocommerce based plugin installed and active in the same site.

Now the problem is the site is throwing 500 Internal Server Error at least once everyday. When ever the error comes up I am adding a space to the end of .htaccess file and saving it, then the site comes back to working state. Likewise, whenever there is 500 error, the site will be up only after I do some neglegible change like adding or removing a space in .htaccess file.
Did anyone face this issue earlier? please suggest.

Comment: Is your code modifying the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Please post the part of the web server's log that shows the 500 error. A few lines before and after will be helpful.

Comment: @jeroen yes there is a plugin I have been using for masking wp-admin in admin url and it is adding few lines of code to the `.htaccess`. Do you mean this additional code could be causing the issue?

Comment: @BryanH I just noticed the error logs which are stating `</IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section` and I found that the matching tag is missing in `.htaccess`. I will try to add this.

Comment: You should start with disabling that plugin as it seems that it causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that a plugin I installed for masking the admin URL is adding its own code to `.htaccess` and this additional plugin generated code has a missing `<IfModule>` tag which is causing the site to throw 500 error frequently. I uninstalled the problematic plugin and the site works fine now with no more 500 errors.